subscribe image data very slow
I tried to send an 1.5M image from one node to another node with topic method. If the image is only sent once, it takes about 10 seconds to receive the image. If the image is sent once a second, publisher work normally and print out 'send success' after each sending, but subscriber could not receive any image.
How should the situation be resolved? Thank you.
